# How to seperate code into train, val and test functions for pytorch cnn?

Tags: python, function, pytorch, train-test-split

I am training a cnn using pytorch and have created a training loop. As I am performing optimisation and experimenting with hyper-parameter tuning, I want to separate my training, validation and testing into different functions. I need to be able to record my accuracy and loss for each function in order to plot graphs. For this I want to create a function which returns the accuracy.

I am pretty new to coding and was wondering the best way to go about this. I feel like my code is a bit messy at the moment. I need to be able to feed in various hyper-parameters for experimentation in my training function. Could anyone offer any advice? Below is what I can so far:

```
def train_model(model, optimizer, data_loader,  num_epochs, criterion=criterion):
  total_epochs = notebook.tqdm(range(num_epochs))

  for epoch in total_epochs:
    model.train()

    train_correct = 0.0
    train_running_loss=0.0
    train_total=0.0

    for i, (img, label) in enumerate(data_loader['train']):
      #uploading images and labels to GPU
      img = img.to(device)
      label = label.to(device)

      #training model
      outputs = model(img)

      #computing losss
      loss = criterion(outputs, label)

      #propagating the loss backwards
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      train_running_loss += loss.item()
    
      _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
      train_total += label.size(0)
      train_correct += predicted.eq(label).sum().item()
      
    train_loss=train_running_loss/len(data_loader['train'])
    train_accu=100.*correct/total

    print('Train Loss: %.3f | Train Accuracy: %.3f'%(train_loss,train_accu))
```

I have also experimented with making a functions to record accuracy:

```
def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim = 1)
    return torch.tensor(torch.sum(preds == labels).item() / len(preds))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that:

- Unless you have some specific motivation, validation (and testing) should be performed on a different dataset than the training set, so you should use a different `DataLoader`. The computation time will increase because of an additional for loop at every epoch.
- Always call `model.eval()` before validation/testing.

That said, The signature of the validation function is pretty much similar to that of `train_model`

```py
# criterion is passed if you want to register the validation loss too
def validate_model(model, eval_loader, criterion):
   ...
```

Then, in `train_model`, after each epoch, you can call the function `validate_model` and store the returned metrics in some data structure (`list`, `tensor`, etc.) that will be used later for plotting.

At the end of the training, you can then use the same `validate_model` function for testing.

Instead of coding the accuracy by yourself, you can use `Accuracy` from [TorchMetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Finally, if you feel the need to level up, you can use DL training frameworks like [PyTorch Lightning](https://www.pytorchlightning.ai/) or [FastAI](https://pypi.org/project/fastai/). Give also a look at some hyperparameter tuning library such as [Ray Tune](https://www.ray.io/ray-tune).